# How to copy data along a dimension while avoiding unique name constraint issues in Oracle

Tags: oracle, exception, stored-procedures

Database is Oracle 18c

**Data info:**

We have the temporal notion of Seasons, and we have a set of Business Groups in each Season. My table, *AGROUP*, has columns(ID*[auto-generated], NAME, SEASON_ID). Group Names must be unique by Season. Said another way, I can have two groups with the same name **ONLY** if they are in different seasons.

**Task At Hand:**

I need to create a stored procedure that, given a *source season* and a *target season*, can copy all the groups from the source season to the target season. This part is easy enough. The naive solution is:

```
PROCEDURE COPY_GROUPS(IN_SOURCE_SEASON_ID IN SEASON.ID%TYPE,
                      IN_TARGET_SEASON_ID IN SEASON.ID%TYPE)
AS 

WITH SOURCE AS 
      (SELECT AG.ID AS AG_ID,
              AG.NAME,
              AG.SEASON_ID
       FROM AGROUP AG
       WHERE AG.SEASON_ID = IN_SOURCE_SEASON_ID)

INSERT INTO AGROUP (NAME, SEASON_ID)
SELECT SRC.NAME,
       IN_TARGET_SEASON_ID AS SEASON_ID,
FROM SOURCE SRC;
COMMIT;
END;
```

The tricky bit is that it is possible that there exists a group in the target season that already has the same name as a group in the source season. Without intervention, this would generate a unique constraint error. In this case, we want to copy the group but re-name it to something unique. Any method to rename is fine, but my first thought is simply to rename with a suffixed number. To do this, I suppose I would change things around to open a `REFCURSOR` and loop through, inserting one at a time and catching the unique constraint error and responding with a re-attempt to insert with a number suffixed. I'm really in-experienced with routing error handling like this in Oracle however. I could really use some pointing in the right direction.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around with this a bit.  I'd say to try to do the conditional logic in a case statement as per the following example.  You'll need a better way to generate sequences though.

```
/* INSERT INTO AGROUP (id, NAME, SEASON_ID) */
WITH agroup as 
(
select 1 id, 'A' name, 1 season_id from dual union
select 2 id, 'A' name, 2 season_id from dual union
select 3 id, 'B' name, 1 season_id from dual union
select 4 id, 'C' name, 2 season_ud from dual
)
, SOURCE AS 
(SELECT rownum row_num, AG.ID AS AG_ID,
AG.NAME,
AG.SEASON_ID
FROM AGROUP AG
WHERE AG.SEASON_ID = 1 /* source season */
)
SELECT /* sequence generation */ (select max(id) from agroup) + row_num as id
,      case when SRC.NAME in (select name 
                              from agroup 
                              where agroup.season_id = 2 /* target season */ 
                                and agroup.name = src.name
                             )
            then src.name || ' ' || to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY hh24:MI:SS')
            else src.name
       end as name
, 2 /* target season */ AS SEASON_ID
FROM SOURCE SRC
;
```